# Remove custom error in my mvc app?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

Hey i have an mvc app that i have published in my azure server. I get an error when i try it in the server. In localhost in works fine. But in the server i get an error that looks like this

[image]

So my question is how can i remove that custom error. I want to see the error message that explains what the error is about?

i want the error message to be like this one

[image]

Comment: Don't post links to images, post the images in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if you have this line this line in your web config system.web area

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

if you do change it to off and if not add it in

Comment: You can also do this in IIS

Answer (score 0):

You can use web.config transform file (such as Web.Debug.config or Web.Release.config) and include the following section:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
</system.web>
```

The Web.config file will be transformed when you deploy to Azure. The transform does not occur locally.